# How to get a config file provider plugin configuration using python client?

Tags: python, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, configuration-files

I have Jenkins instance with the Config File Provider Plugin installed, and I have configured some files using this plugin. I want to retrieve the configuration of these files programmatically using the Python Jenkins client library.

I have tried using the jenkins.Jenkins class from the Python Jenkins library to get the configuration, but I am getting a 404 error for the URL
`http://<JENKINS_URL>/computer/%7B'classpath':%20'config-file-provider'%7D/scriptText.`

Here's the code I tried:

import jenkins

```
# Connect to Jenkins
server = jenkins.Jenkins('http://<JENKINS_URL>')

# Get configuration of Config File Provider Plugin
config = server.run_script('configFileProvider.getConfigFileById("<CONFIG_FILE_ID>")')
```

I am getting the following error:

```
requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 404 Client Error: Not Found for url: http://<JENKINS_URL>/computer/%7B'classpath':%20'config-file-provider'%7D/scriptText
```

How can I correctly retrieve the configuration of a file configured using the Config File Provider Plugin in Jenkins using the Python Jenkins client library? Any help or guidance would be appreciated.